# Using Pagy with Filtered Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagy

```ruby
@animals = @animals.select{|animal| animal.temporary_home == home_params }
@animals = .... additional filters

@pagy, @animals = pagy(@animals)
```

I'm new to pagy and I keep running into this error when I attempt to apply filtering to the data

```
17:23:03 web.1  | NoMethodError (undefined method `offset' for []:Array):
```

If I do not apply filtering, the following works:

```
@pagy, @animals = pagy(Animal.all)
```

Is it possible to use Pagy with filtered data?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is pagy actually works on `ActiveRecord::Collection` since `@animals` is an array the methods for `ActiveRecord::Collection` wont be present on it.

`Pagy` includes another extention (?) to work with arrays. check out

https://ddnexus.github.io/pagy/extras/array.html#gsc.tab=0

```rb
require 'pagy/extras/array'

@animals = @animals.select{|animal| animal.temporary_home == home_params }
@animals = .... additional filters

@pagy, @animals = pagy_array(@animals)
```